# Azure SQL Server - consideration

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

There are a few options for Azure SQL Server

1. Vanilla Azure SQL Server (SaaS)
2. Azure SQL Server using VM image (IaaS)
3. Azure SQL Server Alwayson

I'm trying to understand what option replaces the best an on-premises SQL server accessed by multiple servers, that will become multiple "callers" in Azure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well that really depends on what your requirements are. An Azure VM with SQL would be the closet to replacing a physical SQL server and you can setup clusters and failover and all that. You really should read more into them at http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/services/sql-database/

Comment: Thank you.
I have reviewed documentation and one page has a flow to make decision very easy: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2013/02/14/choosing-between-sql-server-in-windows-azure-vm-amp-windows-azure-sql-database.aspx